# Como consigo o angulo de um gradiente de uma imagem, usando Python e OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Preciso conseguir o ângulo do gradiente de uma imagem, estou programando em Python e usando o Google Colab para os códigos.

Encontrei esse código aqui, que deveria me mostrar o ângulo do gradiente:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('./dt.jpg',0)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_32F,1,0,ksize=3)
sobely= cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_32F,0,1,ksize=3)
phase=cv2.phase(sobelx,sobely,angleInDegrees=True)
print(phase)
```

mas também encontrei esse outro codigo que deveria me mostrar o ângulo:

```
gx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)
gy = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)
print("\nX\n", gx, "\nY\n", gy)
mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(gx, gy)
print("\nMAG\n",mag,"\nANG\n",ang)
```

Ambos me retornam Arrays, mas como converto essa informação para o grau de um ângulo? ou existe uma outra forma para conseguir esse resultado?

Comment: Acho que você está confundindo o que a função [Sobel](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html) realiza. Ela retorna um vetor com as derivadas de vários pontos de gradiente na imagem, utilizado para encontrar bordas. Então, ao encontrar o ângulo de Sobel com [phase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22383252/7690982) ou cart2polar, você obtém um vetor com todos os ângulos destas derivadas...

Comment: Entendi, achei que eu teria que calcular o ângulo com o vetor que o método retornava, Obrigado!